# How to update "alen" function to "len" function

Tags: 20.04, python3, numpy

i I'm having problems running code, I'm new to this so I dont really know that much. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox 6.1.36 and so far I've installed Laplack and Blas libraries, gfortran, python3 with pip3, numpy and pandas, matplotlib, PyQT5, Gnome, pint and git. All this is so I can run a GitHub code, but when I try to run it I get this problem:

```
/thermopack/addon/pycThermopack$ python3 thermopack_gui.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thermopack_gui.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gui.widgets.change_mode import GoToPlotModeWidget, GoToCalcModeWidget
  File "/home/felipe/thermopack/addon/pycThermopack/gui/widgets/change_mode.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gui.widgets.calc_mode import CalcMode
  File "/home/felipe/thermopack/addon/pycThermopack/gui/widgets/calc_mode.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pint
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pint/_init_.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .measurement import Measurement
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pint/measurement.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .quantity import Quantity
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pint/quantity.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .numpy_func import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pint/numpy_func.py", line 855, in <module>
    implement_func("function", func_str, input_units=None, output_unit=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pint/numpy_func.py", line 263, in implement_func
    func = getattr(np, func_str_split[0])
  File "/home/felipe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/_init.py", line 311, in __getattr_
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'alen'
```

I've read somewhere that this happens because "alen" is an old function and now it is called just "len", but I don't know how to change this or how to tell Ubuntu to change the function. Help me please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know how to change this or how to tell Ubuntu to change the function

```
grep alen thermopack_gui.py
```

and visually check the results all point to a function (related to numpy).

```
cp thermopack_gui.py thermopack_guiORG.py
vi thermopack_gui.py
```

Use `:/alen` and change each to what you need (if is is `numpty.alen` change it to `len`) and save it.

`alen` was a numpy function and got removed in 1.18.0. It could be you need to change more.